# Issue with saving current page to database via $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']

Tags: php

I'm having a strange issue where I'm saving the last page a visitor or member was on into the database.

For some reason, it's saving files like `ckeditor.js` into the database instead of the home page URL. I'm not sure why, when I echo out `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` on the page it shows the right page name. But in the database, it says something similar to what I mentioned above. Like it's loading that file as a page? I don't know...

I've done testing on my account membership to make sure my username was saved in the database too and someone wasn't browsing to `ckeditor.js`, and I was right, it still saves incorrectly to the database.

I actually just tested it to save all entries, and it gives me three entries.
The page name, then a `jquery.js` file, the `ckeditor.js` file. I don't know why.

```
$select_variable = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO table(last_page) VALUES (?)");
$stmt->bind_param('s', $select_variable);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->close();
```

Anyone have any advice?

Comment: Share your code too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably, you have an HTML document (at the homepage URL) which has `<script src="jquery.js"></script>` and `<script src="ckeditor.js"></script>` in it.

So:

1. The browser requests the homepage
2. The server puts the homepage URL in the database and sends the homepage to the browser
3. The browser parses the HTML and discovers it needs to load the scripts
4. The browser requests `jquery.js`
5. The server puts the `jquery.js` URL in the database and sends the JS to the browser
6. The browser requests `ckeditor.js`
7. The server puts the `ckeditor.js` URL in the database and sends the JS to the browser

Either stop the PHP running when the JS files are requested (i.e. serve them statically) or add a test to skip the DB stuff when it is a JS file.

Comment: You lead me to figuring out some answers to this. There were two issues I had with the hrefs path. I fixed that though and those two files aren't showing up now. (I've been up for 2 days and added new js files to the site). but apparently it was pulling the files as a "page" I assume since the files weren't actually there.

Answer (score -1):

You should be using `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` to figure out the last page user was.

`REQUEST_URI` is used for URI for the current page. Hope, it helps.